# Optimized code for updating table index values, when a random row is deleted

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with an android app which needs some DB operations and for the same I use the below code. My reason for using this code is because I am using data pulled from my table to be displayed on a ListView and I need to delete a random list - the only relationship i can find between ListView and my table is the list position and index value of the table. the list gets updated automatically but not the table index.

```
public void deleteValues(int position) 
{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        position = position + 1;
        String id = String.valueOf(position);
        db.delete(FUEL_TABLE, KEY_ID + "="+id,null);
//Updating table

        String CREATE_TABLE_COPY = "CREATE TABLE " + "COPIED_TABLE" + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_PRICE + " TEXT," + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT," + KEY_FUELID + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_COPY);
        String db_insert_command;
        db_insert_command = "INSERT INTO COPIED_TABLE (" + KEY_DATE +", " + KEY_TIME + ", " + KEY_PRICE + ", " + KEY_AMOUNT + ", " + KEY_FUELID + ") " +
                "SELECT " + KEY_DATE +", " + KEY_TIME + ", " + KEY_PRICE + ", " + KEY_AMOUNT + ", " + KEY_FUELID + " FROM "+ FUEL_TABLE;
        System.out.println(db_insert_command);
        db.execSQL(db_insert_command);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + FUEL_TABLE);
//Creating FUEL_TABLE again
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + FUEL_TABLE + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_PRICE + " TEXT," + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT," + KEY_FUELID + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + FUEL_TABLE + " SELECT * FROM COPIED_TABLE");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE COPIED_TABLE");
        db.close();
}
```

I created this function to do all the DB operations. This will create a new temporary table and copy all the contents from the original table after the random deletion process. (Now the index value of the table may be like 1,2,3,5,6... where the row with index 4 is deleted. So the temporary table will create new rows with ascending index perfectly. This temp table is then copied to the original table after the original table is created again.

My `OnItemLongClickListener`

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        final int pos, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    alert.setTitle("Fuel Calculator");

                    // set dialog message
                    alert
                        .setMessage("Delete this entry?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                db.deleteValues(pos);
                                System.out.println("Performing delete from DB and populating Listsview again");
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListviewActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                          })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
```

My Adapter

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, Items,
                    R.layout.list_item,new String[] { "date","time", "amount", "price" },
                    new int[] {R.id.date, R.id.time, R.id.price, R.id.capacity });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I think this logic and code is crap. I think there are better ways to do the same. Please help

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but isn't it easier to assume that they're not necessarily sequential? Any particular reason that you need to? If the user is low on space and tries to delete something, he/she won't be able to delete since that currently requires _more_ space.

Comment: you mean that you create table from original table and then delete original table and putting all values from temp table to original table. why you need that??

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have specifyed my particular reason in the edit

Comment: @ArmaanStranger yes am doing the same, I have my own reasons please read the edit

Comment: post your adapter code.

Comment: If your adapter works as it should, `onListItemClick()` should give you the id, not just the position, of the item clicked so that - not the position - should probably be your relationship.

Comment: Edited, posted adapter and clicklistener. @JoachimIsaksson I have tried many ways, I don't think I got an id for my list items.

Comment: @Balavishnu What is the value of `id` when `onListItemClick()` is called? Always zero, or `_id` of the actual database row?

Comment: it matches the list position with the id of the actual database row and delete the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are searching for a method to link the list position and db id, I don't think there is any. Your above code helped me to do something similar.

Comment: What about [Adapter.getItemId(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int))????

Answer (score 1):

Instead of SimpleAdapter you should use CursorAdapter which is specifically intended for such cases. You only need to name your table primary key as "_id". In that case you can always obtain your DB key for ListView item by calling **getItemId(position)** and then delete the required record from DB. Something as below where **lv** is your ListView:

```
public void deleteValues(int position) 
{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(FUEL_TABLE, KEY_ID + "="+lv.getItemId(position),null);
        db.close();
}
```

And certainly you should forget all this CREATE/COPY/DROP table doing. Search for CursorAdapter examples.